# How to properly deal with a callback stack

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a module that looks something like this:

```js
function MyMod(){}

MyMod.prototype.doSomething = function(handler){
  //do stuff
  var callback = function(){
    //doStuff
    handler();
    
  };
  anotherModule.doSomething(callback);
}


module.exports = MyMod
```

This works fine however I don't want to embed the actual callBack method inside my doSomething method so I tried following:

```js
    function MyMod(){}

    MyMod.prototype.doSomething = function(handler){
      this.handler = handler;
      anotherModule.doSomething(this.someCallBack);
    }

    MyMod.prototype.someCallBack = function(){
        //doStuff
        this.handler();
      }

    module.exports = MyMod
```

This seems a bit more cleaner and is easier to extend however this does not seem to work. 
I seem to notice that when doing this approach, he seems to lose the context of the object and this.handler is undefined.

How is a concept like this properly handled in node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in JavaScript refers to the current context. You can change the context by using `.apply` and `.call`, eg:

```
var fn = function() {  
    console.log(this);  
};
fn.call({}); // {}
fn.call([1,2,3]); // [1,2,3]
```

This means that when piping functions to other modules etc you have to care about what `this` is refering to:

```
var moduleA = { 
    fn: function() { 
        // logic
        this.fn2();
    }, 
    fn2: function() {
        // more logic
    }
};
var moduleB = { 
    fn: function(callback) { 
        // logic
        callback();
    }
}; 

moduleB.fn(moduleA.fn); // TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This happens because when `moduleA.fn` is called the context (`this`) is set to the global context: `moduleA.fn -> fn -> fn()`, to prevent this you can use `.bind(context)`

```
var fn = function() { console.log(this, arguments) };
var fnBound = fn.bind({});

fnBound(); // {};
fnBound.call([1,2,3]); // {} even works if people are trying to change the context
```

*Written with focus on your 2. solution.*

With our test before with `moduleA` and `moduleB`:

```
var moduleA = { 
    fn: function() { 
        // logic
        this.fn2();
    }, 
    fn2: function() {
        // more logic
    }
};
var moduleB = { 
    fn: function(callback) { 
        // logic
        callback();
    }
}; 

moduleB.fn(moduleA.fn.bind(moduleA)); // works
```

Sugar:

```
var fn = function() { console.log(this); };

// Bind context = {}; 
// Bind arguments[0] = 1
// Call with arguments = [2, 3]
// Final: context = {}, arguments = [1,2,3]
fn.bind({}, 1)(2, 3);
```